# Ejecución del codigo php

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con el código php que he elaborado ,ya que, a la hora de enviar el formulario html el código php lejos de ejecutármelo y enviarme los datos a mysql me sale impreso en el navegador.

Este es el código php el cual me lo imprime el navegador pero no me lo ejecuta:

```
<?php


$conectar = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password', 'stats');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost:3306');
exit;
if(!$conectar){
    echo "No conectado";
}
else{

$playerwins = $_POST['playerwins'];
$machinewins = $_POST['machinewins'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO playerstats(playerwins,machinewins)values('$playerwins','$machinewins')";

$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);
}

if(!$ejecutar){
    echo "Hay algun error";
}
else{
    echo "Datos almacenados correctamente";
}
?>
```

Comment: suena a que no tienes un interprete de php instalado. Quizas utilizas php con apache, o php-fpm, o has arrancado el servidor de php que viene incorporado a partir de la version 7?

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu sistema operativo? Deberías verificar en consola si tienes PHP debidamente instalado.

Comment: Debes tener un SGBB como APPSERV, APACHE, WAMPP, XAMPP, etc y pegar el archivo.php en la ruta c:/appserv/www o c:/wampp(xampp)/htdocs y abrir el archivo desde navegador así localhost/archivo.php

Comment: Por qué tiene exit en la tercera linea?  Además,Access-Control-Allow-Origin dice al navegador que permita tráfico del puerto 3306 de localhost, lo cual es MySQL.  Quiere que MySQL envie HTML directamente al navegaor?

Answer (score 0):

intenta de esta manera quite el encabezado ya que como te mencionan arriba estas intentando que mysql se conecte directamenete con el navegador, ademas que manda un error al ejecutarlo el exit lo mande abajo porque sales de tu ejecucion antes y no ejecutaba las demas lineas de codigo.
espero haberte ayudado

```
    <?php

     $conectar = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password', 'stats');


     if(!$conectar){
        echo "No conectado";
     }
     else{

     $playerwins = $_POST['playerwins'];
     $machinewins = $_POST['machinewins'];**texto en negrita**

     $sql = "INSERT INTO playerstats(playerwins,machinewins)
     values($playerwins,$machinewins)";

     $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);
     
     }

     if(!$ejecutar){
        echo "Hay algun error";
     }
     else{
        echo "Datos almacenados correctamente";
     }

     exit;
    ?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu interés y ayuda pero lamentablemente me sigue sin funcionar, seguiré probando cosas pero ya no se que mas puedo hacer, he hecho de todo.

Comment: Ya me funciona,lo que tenia que hacer para que el código funcionara bien era abrir el archivo desde la carpeta de xampp y ejecutar el codigo php desde alli